# Help with a simple Apache 'hello world' index file. Here is the tutorial I'm using as well

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Here is the tutorial I'm using, just so that you know where I'm places my file. In fact, I'm using the duckling.org example in the tutorial as my own example. Here is the link:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#configure_apache_for_named_based_virtual_hosting

I'm trying to do I simply 'hello world' to see if apache is configured correctly. I've got my vhost files and i've done a2ensite mysite.org, the restarted and reloaded apache and now i have a static page that says "Index of /" Where do I place my html file that prints out hello world? I thought I could just create an index.html file in /srv/www/ducklington.org/ with the html and it would print but that's not the case. :/ I'm trying to do I simply 'hello world' to see if apache is configured correctly. I've got my vhost files and i've done a2ensite mysite.org, the restarted and reloaded apache and now i have a static page that says "Index of /" Where do I place my html file that prints out hello world? I thought I could just create an index.html file in /srv/www/ducklington.org/ with the html that says 'hello world' and it would print but that's not the case.

j.

Answer (score 1):

Hard for me to say much without seeing the config files (can you post a link to your config files?) but if you can point your browser at ducklington.org and get an "index of /" the vhost seems to be working somewhat ;) It also often help me to look at the access_log and the error_log from apache...

just to clarify in the link you posted it says "DocumentRoot /srv/www/bucknell.net/public_html/", so you put your index.html with the hello world into /srv/www/ducklington.org/public_html/index.html?